# How do you convert the number you get from datepart to the name of the day?

Tags: sql-server, datepart

Is there a quick one-liner to call datepart in Sql Server and get back the name of the day instead of just the number?

```
select datepart(dw, getdate());
```

This will return 1-7, with Sunday being 1.  I would like 'Sunday' instead of 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select datename(weekday, getdate());
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually took me more searching than I thought it would to find this answer.  It's funny how you can use a technology for ages and never know about simple functions like this.

```
select datename(dw,  getdate())
```

I'm not sure how localization would work with this function.  Getting the name client-side is probably the answer, but it would be nice to do it on the database.  Would Sql Server use the collation setting to determine the output for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using the result to select the day yourself. For one thing the textual representation of the day is locale-dependent. For another the returned value depends upon the 'datefirst' setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a localizable solution, just join the result against a table with the names and numbers.