# Group by 24 hour and Day of week - time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know this is a common question, but I couldn't find something that matches my case. So here we go.

I have a table named RECORDED_ENTRIES that has columns ID (int) and CreateDate (datetime).

I want to group data by hour on a 24hour basis regardless of the actual date.

For example I want the output to be:

```
00:00 - 2
01:00 - 3
02-00 - 12
....
23:00 - 1
```

The aim is to create data for a chart that will display recorded entries by the hour of day

I need to group also data by the name of Day.

Thanks

Comment: Is grouping by DAY good enough? or does it have to be an exact 24 hour timespan from the current time?

Comment: actually i would need both :) I am asking for the 24hour interval and then I guess i can figure out how the grouping by day would work. But any help is appreciated

Comment: for the above question, i don't need the grouping by date. You see , i have entries recorded in various days. So i want to get the trend (in which time of the day most entries are recorded etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,CreateDate)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99d82/2)

Comment: Oh yes, that's what i want!!. What about grouping the results by the name of day instead of by hour?

Comment: @MaVRToSCy Please, check out DATEPART function. It has all options to get different parts of Datetime - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @MaVRoSCy DATEPART(weekday,CreateDate) or DATEPART(dw,CreateDate) is for day of the week. The return value depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST. (Whatever 1 is Sunday or Monday)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533/how-do-you-convert-the-number-you-get-from-datepart-to-the-name-of-the-day

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONVERT() function in sql server which acts like CAST() but you can use styles! convert(varchar(2),,108) will use the 108-code which is HH:MM:SS.
Check out http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Example:

```
DECLARE@d DATETIME= '2013-03-02 19:45';
SELECT
@d AS dt
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@d,108) AS theHour
```